# Waiting with timeout - Windows

Tags: c++, windows, semaphore

My program , in C++, has a thread that insets data to a buffer, and another thead that reads this data.
when there is no more data to read, I wan to wait till the other thread inserts new data. 
I mostly work on linux, but I dont know how to do it in Windows.
the most similar thing that I've found is the "WaitForSingleObject" function, but it's not exactly what I need since I dont want to wail till the thread that inserts data is dead.

can someone please direct me to a place I can read about this more?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WaitForSingleObject with timeout. Your thread that inserts data might signal to your reader thread that no more data is available. Here is some good reading on this subject:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Boost.Thread offers [condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref), that you can use portably.

If your compiler supports it, you can instead use C++11's [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: I prefer not using Boost. I've been told that it's overkill.

Comment: If I am not misteaken, threading in c++11 was based on Boost.Thread

Comment: @kakush Seriously, who told that? In any case I think you should at least try it, after which you can make an informed decision yourself on whether it's an overkill or not. Or you can avoid Boost and welcome platform dependent code, clumsy C-style interfaces, more chances for bugs and whatnot; the choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

In windows `WaitForSingleObject` can wait for many type of handles for example handle of a thread, handle of an event, semaphore or even mutex, so this function is to wait for an object to become signaled, you are not forced to wait for other thread to become dead!:)

```
// Global
HANDLE hHasData = CreateSemaphore(
    NULL, // Security attribute, NULL means default
    0,    // Initial count of semaphore
    100,  // Maximum count of semaphore
    NULL  // Name of semaphore, will be used to share it between processes
    );

// Producer thread
auto data = produce_data();
push_data_to_queue( data );
ReleaseSemaphore( hHasData );

// Consumer thread
while( true ) {
    WaitForSingleObject( hHasData, INFINITE );
    auto data = pop_data_from_queue();
    process_data( data );
}
```

Also if you care for cross platform code, you can use C++11 threading and synchronization objects like `std::condition_variable` or its counterpart `boost::condition_variable`

Comment: @kakush If you never use `boost` til now just try it and you will see that it is one of the best libraries that ever written! it is awesome and if anybody told you that `boost` is overkill think about its programming skill!!

Comment: thanks @BigBoss, but do I really need to use "ReleaseSemaphore" everyTime I'm inserting data and also I dont need to use WaitForSingleObject every time I want to read data, because maybe there is data in the buffer ? I only want to signal only if the reading thread couldnt read anything, because I might send ReleaseSemaphore twice ( lock+=2) and when there is no more data to read I'll use WaitForSingleObject (lock-=1), and then I'll be in a problem. BTW - the thread that inserts data , inserts it in chunks, and the readerthread need to wait till few chuncks are inserted..

Comment: @kakush This is up to your design, you should think about semaphore as a waitable counter, so for every inserted data you will add it by one and for every peekup of data you will decrease it(`WaitForSingleObject` decrease semaphore count)! that's all, and you should a lock free list in between to avoid any other kind of locking, but at the other side you may have a list that protected by a lock(mutex for example) and a manual reset event that will be set to signaled when you insert data to the list and reset to non-signaled when it is empty! but in my opinion lock free list+semaphore is better